# Public CiviEvents Showing as Private

Tags: civievent

Using CiviCRM 4.6.8 and Wordpress 4.3.2, all of my Event Info pages and Registration pages show as being private even though I've selected public and the Manage Events interface lists them as public. Regardless, visitors to the site are unable to access these pages.

I'm really not sure what I could be missing here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Administer > System Settings > CMS Database Integration, my WordPress Base Page was set to "civicrm". I removed that value and now everything works, with anonymous users having access to view my event pages.

Comment: Interesting - but not advisable for most installs because the homepage template supplied by many themes does not call `the_content()`. Did your install have a corresponding WordPress page called "CiviCRM" with the slug "civicrm"?

Comment: The other option that worked for me was to leave the base page as civicrm and set the WordPress "CiviCRM" page to public visibility. Not sure if this is the smarter approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that users have the right permission in the CMS?

'CiviEvent: view event info'

Comment: Yes, all the Wordpress roles have a check mark for 'CiviEvent: view event info'

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are experiencing the same issue I had.  Here's a link to that topic:
[Bug or feature? Logged in, can't do event registration. Not logged in, Event Registration loads](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/888/bug-or-feature-logged-in-cant-do-event-registration-not-logged-in-event-reg)